# How facebook load the loaded content into the div

Tags: html

I have noted that when i click one link on the facebook the content is not loaded on the div, but i have check the facebook page source and there is no iframe. Did anybody know how they are loading the page into a div. If anybody know pls help.

I will more clear my question, i just need to know what happend in facebook when we click the facebook logo on the left side the browser loading but by checking the source the page not loaded on the iframe. If they are loading the page using ajax how the browser loading. Hope you get my question. Thanks

Comment: You couldn't possibly be more vague.

Comment: Ajax? Have you just looked up the scripts on that particular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AJAX. You can achieve a similar effect using the JQuery JS framework and it's inbuilt `.load()` function.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks but is it loading the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by loading the browser. Facebook is built in PHP and HTML. What you see when the URL is updated is the changing of variables stored in the URL and not the change of the webpage itself. For example, `http://facebook.com/?ref=Logo` to `http://facebook.com/?profile_id=123456` is still calling the same file, index.php, but changing the GET variables to cause a different outcome.